# magento, error when reindexing Catalog URL Rewrites

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

All this afte rupgrading from 1.4.1

I get a quite specific error message:

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'product/19-1-2' for key 'UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID'' in /home/in-due/domains/sb2.in-due.de/public_html/hochzeitsshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234

problem is, that I don't know how to find the entry, that is making trouble. neither in the backend (catalog|URL Rewrite Management) nor in the db itself (table core_url_rewrite) is an entry

> product/19-1-2

any help is appreciated,

PAT ERLER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@perler, here is a MySQL query to detect duplicate SKUs. Remember, if you prefixed your tables, change `catalog_product_entity` accordingly!

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(`sku`) as `sku`,
    COUNT(`sku`) as `skuCount`,
    entity_id
FROM
    catalog_product_entity
GROUP BY
    `sku`
HAVING
    `skuCount` > 1;
```

Comment: No problem! I had a similar issue, but in my case it was actually caused by the "level" property of the assigned category being set to 1 instead of 2 in sub-categories. ([more info](http://slightlyremarkable.com/post/18954322031/magento-cant-reindex-catalog-url-rewrites))

Comment: I have another shop where an extension developer thinks that my categories are broken. Maybe I have the same problem. How can I see which category is in which level or if it is in the wrong one?

Comment: Simple. Look at the `level` column on the `catalog_category_entity` table.

Comment: SELECT
  v.value `category_name`,
  c.entity_id,
  v.store_id,
  v.attribute_id,
  a.attribute_code `attribute_code`,
  a.attribute_id
 FROM
  catalog_category_entity c
 LEFT JOIN
  eav_attribute a
 ON
  (a.attribute_code = 'name')
 LEFT JOIN
  catalog_category_entity_varchar v
 ON
  (v.entity_id = c.entity_id AND v.attribute_id = a.attribute_id)
 WHERE
  c.level > 1
  AND
  v.store_id = 0
  AND
  v.attribute_id IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY
  c.entity_id ASC;

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate entry is for a key made up from 3 fields, id_path, is_system and store_id, in theory you should be able to use URL Rewrite Management, search for an id_path of product/19 and this is your 'troublesome' field. Deleting that value may solve the issue (but I'd recommend making a backup first, and trying it in a dev environment first).

If you are still in development and haven't used any custom rewrites you could just empty the core_url_rewrite table and re-index to regenerate all the fields. If it is a live site this would be a little more troublesome, it would mean losing a bit of SEO juice if you have renamed products, since you would lose the rewrite.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I found multiple entries for id_path product/19 (in the backend) which didn't look very suspicious (we have 3 store views and there where three entries, one for each store). I deleted them anyway (we are in the sandbox) but without success. i still have some product/190 (not 19) but don't think that's the problem.

deleting the whole index is out of the question unfortunately, 5000 products in three stores, this would hit the google ranking to much..

Comment: Best I can guess is it's likely that `Mage_Catalog_Model_Url->generatePath()` returns the same id_path twice for the same product, this would cause a duplicate entry error. But this shouldn't be possible unless you somehow have two level 1 categories in that store, which shouldn't be possible. You could try running the cli indexer located @ shell/indexer.php, by cd'ing into shell/ and running `php indexer.php reindexall`, this may help. Or if your using it you could try disabling flat_catalog_categories/products before running reindex, in-case they are corrupt.

Comment: the error comes up when running indexer.php reindexall. how do I disable flat_catalog_categories/products ?

Comment: another thought, as the error message seems to come directly from MySQL
>SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'product/19-1-2' for key 'UNQ_CORE_URL_REWRITE_ID_PATH_IS_SYSTEM_STORE_ID

shouldn't it be possible to identify the specific table/call in the database? what would be the SQL query for this (I'm not very good in crafting SQL queries..)

Comment: system > configuration > catalog > frontend > use flat catalog *

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem was a duplicate SKU. You shouldn't be able to enter one, but what happened (in magento 1.4.0.1) was, that the client entered a very long SKU which got shortened when saving the product. the shortened part was then identically to another SKU.

so, if yourself have this problem, check you database for duplicate SKUs (can someone post an SQL Query to do this?)